# How to integrate custom data model for CoreML iOS project in swift 3

Tags: python, ios, swift, datamodel, coreml

I have made an data model in python for my own purpose. Is it possible to integrate that model within my iOS project to fulfill some of my purpose?

Comment: In addition to the link @VahanBabayan gave you, here's a really good repo with notes on how he imported his model into CoreML: https://github.com/hollance/MobileNet-CoreML

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate your model to `.mlmodel` file. Try to look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools).